# Batchscript to delete file more than 200kb

Tags: batch-file

can anyone pls explain the below command

`FORFILES /S /M *.imp /C "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 200000 del @file"`

I want to delete the .imp file if the file is more than 200kb. I got the command but when I try to put the path  `//flxxx/g_ff_gg$/CDO_MTK_SMT/Hari krishna/gggg_SCRIPTS/` I am getting an error. Where shall I put the path in the above command.

or is there any command to check the file which is more than 200kb and deletes the file with the given directory

Comment: Have you tried to place in the batch with backslashes?

Comment: On Windows the directory separator is ``\`` and not `/`. And syntax for a UNC path is: `\\ComputerName\ShareName\Directory1\Directory2\FileName.ext` which needs to be enclosed in double quotes if there is anywhere a space in entire path or any other special character output in help of `cmd.exe` on last page in last paragraph which can be read on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`. `forfiles /?`, `if /?`  and `del /?` executed in command prompt window display the help pages for the other commands used here.

Comment: I got solution...thanks for your help  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, I use in such cases, is to first change into the directory. Then call the command and final leave.  `pushd` and `popd` are made for such actions.

```
pushd \\ComputerName\ShareName\Directory1\Directory2
FORFILES /S /M *.imp /C "cmd /c if @fsize gtr 200000 del @file"
popd
```

Comment: @Krish Na You're welcome. It looks you are new to stackoverflow. If you think you get an answer of your question please mark it with the green check arrow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Better to put command in braces in case if `Directory2` does not exist: `pushd ".." && ( command ... && popd )`